# new collation (English_world.1252) is incompatible with the collation of the template database (English_World.1252)

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, pytest-django

I'm trying to test with Django, [pytest-django](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-django/tree/53373573f905ec5e0ec5786f49efdcdca5ae41fd) and PostgreSQL on Windows 11.

But I got the error below:

> psycopg2.errors.InvalidParameterValue: new collation (English_world.1252) is incompatible with the collation of the template database (English_World.1252)

Even though I set `English_World.1252` to `LC_COLLATE` and `LC_CTYPE` in `run_sql()` as shown below. *I wrote the code below to connect to PostgreSQL in `conftest.py` following [the doc](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/database.html#using-a-template-database-for-tests):

```py
# "conftest.py"

import pytest
from django.db import connections
import psycopg2
from psycopg2.extensions import ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT

def run_sql(sql):
    conn = psycopg2.connect(database='postgres', user='postgres', password='admin')
    conn.set_isolation_level(ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(sql)
    conn.close()

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def django_db_setup():
    from django.conf import settings

    settings.DATABASES['default']['NAME'] = 'copied_postgres'

    run_sql('DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS copied_postgres')
    run_sql("""
        CREATE DATABASE copied_postgres 
            LC_COLLATE = 'English_World.1252' # Here
            LC_CTYPE = 'English_World.1252' # Here
            TEMPLATE postgres""")

    yield

    for connection in connections.all():
        connection.close()

    run_sql('DROP DATABASE copied_postgres')
```

And, this is `test_get_username()` below in `test_ex1.py`:

```py
# "test_ex1.py"

@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_get_username():
    user = User.objects.create_user("test-user")
    user.username = "John"
    assert user.get_username() == "John"
```

So, how can I solve the error?